# How to get the absolute path of a file using tkFileDialog?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, dialog

I am using:

```
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb', 
       filetypes=[('Subrip Subtitle File','*.srt')], title='Choose a subtitle file')
```

to get a file object specified by the user.

Is there any way I can get the absolute path of this file from the file object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',filetypes=[('Subrip Subtitle File','*.srt')],title='Choose a subtitle file')
abs_path = os.path.abspath(file.name)
```

Comment: This will work as long as there's no `os.chdir()` call between those two lines.  So in the case of this question it's probably fine, but it's not perfect.  I can't think of a way to do it that will always work off the top of my head.

Comment: I don't know of any good reason to use os.chdir() in a GUI app -- at least, not one that also uses threads, and that's the only way you could get a call to chdir() "between" two lines of source that you control.

Comment: Can this approach be trusted?  In describing the .name attribute of file objects, the python docs say: "This is a read-only attribute and may not be present on all file-like objects."  See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.name

Comment: @IronPillow For actual files it should be safe, however for StringIO objects   (which is file-like) you will get an attribute error.

Answer (score 3):

[`os.path.abspath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) should do what you want, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: This works nicely if I pass a string, but I don't know how to get the path as string from my file object :)

Comment: **Nadia Alramli** `file.name` is only going to return the path that was originally passed in.  If you use `open("test/sample.txt")` and then `os.chdir("/some/other/path")` then `f.name` is still going to return `"test/sample.txt"`

Comment: @Steve, and what is wrong with that? I didn't say file.name will return the full path. I was just answering the OP comment about getting the path as a string from the file object.